# "They had no visible means of subsistence" - What does this statement mean?

Tags: meaning

What does this statement mean?

> They had no visible means of subsistence. ([source](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/subsistence?q=subsistence))

I came across this sentence while I was searching for the meaning of "*subsistence*" in Oxford Advanced Learners Dictionary. I am not sure about what the exact meaning of the above statement is.

Comment: It is essentially the same as "They had no visible income".

Comment: The standard phrase (as I am familiar with it) is 'no visible means of support'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**subsistence**

Since you looked up the word i will add the definition from your link:

> the state of having just enough money or food to stay alive

Thus:

> They had no visible means of subsistence

can mean

> They had no visible means ( they lived in a shanty, their clothes were
>   unkempt, hygiene was abysmal, the two chickens running around their
>   yard were scrawny and their garden was wilted) of **subsistence**.